# NHibernate Version conflicts

Tags: nhibernate

Do I need to create my own build of nHibernate and tools if i want to use the following frameworks in 1 project.

nHibernate

nHibernate Validators

Fluent NHibernate

xVal NHibernate Provider

nHibernate Linq

I am getting "Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate," errors which I believe is because each framework is built against a different version of nHibernate?

Comment: Adding to this it seems

Validators & Linq are built against 2.1 and the rest against 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded 2.0 versions of everything solved this.

Silly me!